# Add WinForms to Console Application using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winforms, opencv

thats my first question here. Im browsing the web the last days but cant find any clear answer.
I have a program (made by an other person) with about 2k lines of Code in 5 header- and 5 sourcefiles. Built in **C++** and Visual Studio 2017. Its connected to cameras making pictures and calculating some stuff using OpenCV and spits out an XML-File, all made as **Console Application**.
So now i will add an **GUI** to this programm. There are not much buttons and stuff i will need, one Form will be enough. Therefore i will somehow add a **WinForms**(File?) or rather change the programm to WinForms.
But how can i do this?

I got the "CppCLR_WinformsProjekt"-App/Template. But somehow i cant add this by ie. Projectname.sln->Add->New Element.. like some did with C#.
Also some did add some Reference but i do not have any to choose there.

Well maybe i am completly barking up the wrong tree. I am really a noob in programming and its not my real profession, but however i should and will **add an GUI to this existing program**.

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to add any pictures yet.

Comment: Does tkinter does for you?

Comment: Never heard of. Seems to be for phyton, doesnt?

Comment: If you have access to the C++ code, I recomend you to: (1) Wrap it in a library with a proper interface. (2) Add a C++/CLI dll that wraps the C++ lib with a .NET interface. (3) Use this C++/CLI interface in C# code for the UI (WinForms or WPF).